# Mock method on the same class with dependency Injection - PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

i was wondering on how i can mock a method on the same class that this class have a dependency itself.

**Let's say an example:**

```
Class SomeClassA {

  protected $dependency;

  function __construct(Dependency $dependency) {

     $this->dependency = $dependency;

  }


  public function methodToTest() {

         if ( !is_null( $this->methodCalled() ) )

            return $this->methodCalled();

         else

            return "it\'s not ok!"

         // need to test this method mocking the methodCalled()

  }


  public function methodCalled($message) {

        return $message;

  }


}
```

if this class did not have the dependency i could do something like so:

```
public function test_methodToTest() {

    $this->getMock('SomeClassA',['methodCalled'])
         ->with('message')
         ->expects($this->once())
         ->will($this->returnValue('message'));

   $someClassA = new SomeClassA();

   $this->assertEquals('message',$someClassA->methodToTest('message'));


}
```

**Edit:**

Let's say this example to improve the meaning of my question i just changed a little bit the previous example:

```
Class SomeClassA {

  protected $dependency;

  function __construct(Dependency $dependency) {

     $this->dependency = $dependency;

  }


  public function methodToTest() {

         if ( $this->methodCalled() ) // i was wondering how mock this method

            return $this->dependency->someDependencyMethod(); // not this

         else

            return "it\'s not ok!"



  }


  public function methodCalled() {

        return true;

  }


}
```

I just didn't understand how I can mock the method `$this->methodClass()`. I found hard it because the class SomeClassA have a dependency. And i'm testing a method of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
class SomeClassATest {
    public function testMethodToTest() {
        $someClassA = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClassA')
            ->setMethods(array('methodCalled'))
            ->getMock();
        $someClassA->expects($this->once())
            ->method('methodCalled')
            ->will($this->returnValue('your mocked value here'));
        $actual = $someClassA->methodToTest();
        $this->assertEquals('your expectation here', $actual);
    }
}
```

This will only work if `methodCalled` is either public or protected, since you can only mock public and protected methods. The way it works up there is you are testing `$someClassA`, a mock instance of `SomeClassA`, where only `methodCalled` is replaced with your test behavior, and everything else stays the same.

Comment: I got it, but then how do you test the method `someDependencyMethod`? because after i did the partial mock how you showed, i cannot mock the dependency and pass it on the instance of of `SomeClassA' because i already instantiate it with the mockBuild. Also you didn't pass the constructor to the SomeClassA mocking. How can it work? Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: You can do $this->getMockBuilder('..')->setConstructorArgs(...), this will allow u to construct your mock object with external dependencies u want.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be doing this a lot with unit tests:

- Mock the dependency.
- Set up expectations on the dependency.
- Inject the mocked dependency into a real, non-mocked object.

To show a real example, your dependency needs to be actually used (which it isn't in your sample code, I think your code may be broken). So lets change your `methodToTest` class to this as an example:

public function methodToTest() {
      return $dependency->returnValue();
  }

So now your `methodToTest` returns a value it gets from dependeency. To test this, lets mock a dependency:

```
$dep = $this->getMock('Dependency');
```

Then lets set expectations and what it returns:

```
$dep->expects($this->once())
     ->method('returnValue')
     ->will($this->returnArgument('hello world'));
```

Here we are saying that the dependency expects `returnValue` to be called once and will return the string 'hello world'.

Now lets test the actual class:

```
$tester = new SomeClassA($dep);
```

Notice we inject the mock dependency into a real `SomeClassA`.

```
$this->assertEquals('hello world',$tester->methodToTest());
```

This assertion is the only 'visible' one. It makes sure that `methodToTest` returns the value from the dependency. The test will also make sure that 'returnValue' function on the dependency is called exactly once.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i'll appreciate you more if you can do some example about it.

Comment: That example is perfect for mock the dependency, but maybe i didn't explained good my problem. if you can take a look i updated my question. Thank you for your time